# Angular how many nesting component allowed in angular

Tags: angular

componet c is nested component b

component b is nested component a

In this way how much level of component nesting is allowed

Comment: I do not believe there is a hard limit.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular Everything is based on Component, As based on this We don't have any limit for nesting component.

Answer (score 0):

I'll have to agree with the other answers and comments.
I never had problems with nested components, also never even had to nest more than maybe 5 components max, too many `@Input`s and `@Output`s will make your code difficult to read.